# C# Get correct filpath string for SQL update Statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have created a small WinForms Application (.Net 4.8, SQL Server 18). Now I want to update a picture in my database. For that I have created this method:

```
public void UpdateBild(string picturepath, int id)
{
    string bildupdate = string.Format("UPDATE {0} set bild = (SELECT  BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK  N'@pic', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x) where persid = @id", Klassen.Data.Gettabellenname());

    try
    {
        SqlVerb();
        com.CommandText = bildupdate;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic", picturepath);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException sqex)
    {

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        DBVerbindung.DBVerb.scon.Close();
    }
}
```

The picturepath will be set like that from a textbox:

```
picturepath = tbDateiPfad.Text;
```

and it will be passed to the method like:

```
DBVerbindung.SQLStatements upbild = new DBVerbindung.SQLStatements();
upbild.UpdateBild(picturepath, id);
```

If the method gets executed, I get the error 'Picture not found'.

I think there is a problem with the file path because, if I execute the UPDATE statement directly in database with the filepath (copy from dircetory search) it is working fine.

So can you please help me, how I can pass the filepath from textbox in correct form to the paramter for the SQL query.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **18** - we have 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 (all unsupported by now), 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019. So take your pick - which one is it you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename must be specified as a string literal instead of parameter for `OPENROWSET` so you'll need to specify that value in the SQL statement string:

```
string bildupdate = string.Format("UPDATE {0} set bild = (SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'{1}', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x) WHERE persid = @id;", Klassen.Data.Gettabellenname(), picturepath);

try
{
    SqlVerb();
    com.CommandText = bildupdate;
    com.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
…
```

Note the table name and file name values must be obtained from trusted sources and validated since the values are not parameterized. Also, [avoid `AddWithValue`](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).